How can I select one of two identical USB power sources while blocking out the other?
I am trying to design a keyboard with two USB-C inputs that connect to host. I decided on using a HD3SS6126 for switching logic.
HD3SS6126 datasheet.
I would like to make it so that when one of the two USBs are plugged in and the 5 V is supplied, it should trigger the SEL pin on the HD3SS6126 (for example, if USB1 is plugged in, the SEL goes high, and if USB2 is plugged in, the SEL goes low, so the HD3SS6126 switch knows which input to route), and also to effectively block the other port from doing anything even if it's plugged in while the first one is still in use.
Here is a brainstorming example I thought up to try and solve this:

Of course, I'm not confident if this will do the trick, so I am asking for help.
Thanks.

EDIT1:
I found this schematic (Thanks @Dave Tweed) but that always prioritizes the top input, regardless of the second one:

I would like to edit this one to prioritize the first plugged.

EDIT2:
I think I may have made something that looks like it works.

Here is a gif to illustrate how it works:
https://s11.gifyu.com/images/SoykM.gif
The documentation says this about the SEL pin:

Please help me validate if this will indeed control the SEL pin as intended?
I was thinking about adding some output diodes to prevent SEL and !SEL leaking towards one another.

EDIT3:
Improved circuit with a voltage delay on one input to prevent the circuit from oscillating if both input arrive at the exact same time (Thanks @BK303 for pointing that out):

Next hurdle: is it also possible to power the rest of the circuit (for ex the MCU and some LEDs etc.) from the preferred voltage source?
Don't sweat the specific power draw, I'm curious in just the concept.

Are both the usb cables connected to the same computer/device so that they have a common ground? Or might one go to one computer, and another to a different computer?

Honestly it shouldn't matter, I would like it to work the same in both scenarios. Simply to keep the input that was plugged in first as active and block the other.

If the cables could possibly be connected to two different devices, then you might want to consider mechanical relays. Often the power supplies of computers/devices have Y capacitors that put a common mode ghost voltage of 1/2 line voltage in the power. Rarely a real problem. However, it is possible that the two devices are wired up differently, and it may be possible that the common mode voltages are out of phase (I need to think about that some more). If so, that might cause a problem. Physically disconnecting the ports would prevent electronic switches from having to deal with the issue.

The circuit in this answer has a status output that could be adapted to drive your USB switch's SEL pin.

@DaveTweed I'm presuming the "Panel" and "Batt" would be equivalent to my USB inputs, and the collector pins of Q1 and Q2 would drive the SEL pin?
I'm only a hobbyist with these ICs that's why I'm asking for a bit of clarification.

Yes. If you follow the link in that answer to the older answer, the diagram is a bit more clear. The upper path in that diagram is the "priority" path.

Found the dual PNP circuit. I'm gonna experiment with that a bit and try to solve this. Thanks

If you anyway have a MCU for the keyboard, you could make the MCU to powet from both PCs and switch to the first plugged, or if it turns off, autoswitch to the other. And you could use a special key combo for switching between the two hosts. But whatever you do, you are not allowed to have a pull-up on USB data wire to a PC which has 5V supply off.

@MathKeepsMeBusy USB and many other interfaces are intended for hot-plugging. This is no different than plugging one USB device to another, like a PC to a printer. Or a laptop to a monitor or TV with HDMI. Yes, I hate devices with ungrounded plugs that give you a shock too but we can't do anything about it, except plug them in while mains plug is disconnected.

@Justme No data wires in this diagram. talking only about power input triggering the SEL pin on the switch

@MilošBokšan Which MCU you have and can you program it to do what you want? If yes, the most simplest thing is to let MCU decide what to do, instead of trying to come up with hardware that can do it.

In the last diagram with 2x P-FET, are the diodes on the gates needed?  Seems like they can be omitted.   Also if the SEL input pin doesn't include internal pull-up, then you don't need the N-FET to drive SEL low, the pull-down would be sufficient as the input is very high-impedance.  Labeling the right side output as not (sel) is mis-leading, as it has same polarity.

The logic described for this application to control SEL is the classic Set-Reset NAND latch (with inverting inputs).  VBUS Power present on only on USB1 should cause the logic output to be reset (assume SEL=0 connects USB1 data to the keyboard internal USB data).  VBUS Power present only on USB2 should cause the logic output to be set (assume SEL=1 connects USB2 data).  When both USB1 and USB2 VBUS are both present, the last selected output state should be maintained (S=1, R=1, out= hold).  When neither USB1 or USB2 VBUS power is present, then the output is "don't care", which is called the "invalid" state of the latch.  All four input USB power states will occur with this system, but perhaps in when both USB VBUS are not present (both USB links disconnected) the keyboard is actually powered off.
The only interesting thing to note is that when an SR latch goes directly from the invalid input state to the hold input state, the latch output is unstable.  So maybe consider what happens to this circuit if both USB power up simultaneously (e.g., if they where connected to a single host computer turning on), does the selection logic circuit stabilize or could it oscillate?

I've added a tiny voltage delay to one of the inputs to make the other the priority in case of them both being plugged in at the same time.
Example: https://i.sstatic.net/Knux4mWG.png
Can this work?

yes, I think you can trust your simulation and try it on a prototype.   If you put on PCB design, then suggest layout would include a placeholder resistor between VBUS and the P-FET source on both sides (not just the side with the R-C), in case testing shows that a small resistor there (maybe 100 ohms) is helpful.  Can always put zero ohm jumper if not needed.
